# How can I make a column in a sharepoint report hidden unless the field is populated?

Tags: sharepoint, knockout.js

I have a report in Sharepoint that I want to show the "End Date" field only if there is an end date. I'm using Knockout

```
  <td class="ms-vb">
                    <b>End Date:</b>
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb">
                    <span data-bind="text: EndDate"></span>
                </td>
```

I just want this part of the report to only be visible if the endDate is populated. Otherwise I don't want it to be seen in the report.

I'm not sure what other information to provide, I think that's sufficient for you to understand my question.
Thanks,

Comment: Your code snippet looks like you're using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to render the HTML. If so, you can use the `visible` binding to hide some content depending on the EndDate.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I'm using knockout. I'll try that out and get back to you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), you can use the [`visible`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding to hide some content based on the end date:

```
<tr data-bind="visible: EndDate() != null">
    <td class="ms-vb">
        <b>End Date:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb">
        <span data-bind="text: EndDate"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `visible` binding, [documented (with examples) here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html).